# countdown timer minutes and seconds problems Java

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans-8

First off, this is not a duplicate question. I just having troubles with the countdown timer and stuffs. Whenever I run the code, it just went static and don't go as planned.

Here's the code. I do it in the constructor. Where I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public static int counterSeconds = 0; 
public static int counterMinutes = 10; 
public static Timer timer; 

public Quiz1Start() {
    do {
        Quiz1Start.timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(Quiz1Start.counterSeconds == 0) {
                    Quiz1Start.counterSeconds = 60;
                    Quiz1Start.counterSeconds--; 
                    Quiz1Start.counterMinutes--;

                    Quiz1Start.jLabelMinute.setText(String.valueOf(counterMinutes)); 
                    Quiz1Start.jLabelSeconds.setText(String.valueOf(counterSeconds));                         
                } else if(Quiz1Start.counterMinutes == 0) {
                    Quiz1Start.timer.stop(); 
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    } while(counterMinutes == 0);
}
```

Comment: I try to put it outside of if-else and before declaring the ActionListener, both of this dont work. ._.

Comment: There is a lot of things which raises questions with me. Why do you loop inside a constructor? And why not in a `start` method for example. Second. For each loop/cycle you construct a new fresh timer with each their own values etc.. What did you expect to happen?  Why checking if minutes are passed within the Timer Listener AND the while-loop? Try to put all that code in a method and invoke it separetly instead from the constructor. Besides remove the while-loop, since it has no use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thank you to user n247s and Uğur B for sharing his ideas, now I got it, I moved the declarations into another new method and then I change the codes into outside of the if-else and it worked! :D

Comment: Not to mentioned that I removed the do-while too, I thought it was needed for repeating the countdown especially for minutes..

Answer (score 0):

Check this part - while(counterMinutes==0);

You defined |counterMinutes| as 10. The loop will not go after first round.

I suppose it should be

```
do {
...
} while(counterMinutes!=0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea sir, but it didn't work. I guess there is still things that were need to be configured in the actionPerformed...